# Excel VBA Fill Series

Tags: excel, vba

I need to fill a range from 10,000 all the way until the end of the column. I have the lRow variable that is finding the last row, and then I have the IF loop that is filling the range just like I need to. The clear contents part is to remove any previous values and fill new ones. The Range("E2").Value = 1 is there to start the series.

The problem is I can't get it to fill the Range("F2:F" & lRow) in a step value of 10,000. The macro just fills out in a step value of 1. Any ideas?

I've tried recording macros but it never works quite right. It needs to be sort of dynamic as the list will grow over time.

This is what it should look like:
[image]

```
Sub MLOS_PriorityTable_StepValues()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim featOrder As Range
Dim Style As Range
Dim dataRange As Range
Dim currentArea As Range


Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set featOrder = ws.Range("A1:ZZ1").Find("FeatureOrder")
Set Style = ws.Range("A1:ZZ1").Find("Style")


Range("E2:E1000").ClearContents
Range("F2:F1000").ClearContents


Range("E2").Value = 1
Range("F2").Value = 10000


    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Style.Column).End(xlUp).Row

    On Error Resume Next
    Set dataRange = Range("E2:E" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not dataRange Is Nothing Then
        For Each currentArea In dataRange.Areas
            With currentArea
                With .Offset(-1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count + 1)
                    .Cells(1).AutoFill Destination:=.Cells, Type:=xlFillSeries
                End With
            End With
        Next currentArea
    End If


    On Error Resume Next
    Set dataRange = Range("F2:F" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not dataRange Is Nothing Then
        For Each currentArea In dataRange.Areas
            With currentArea
                With .Offset(-1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count + 1)
                    .Cells(1).AutoFill Destination:=.Cells, Type:=xlFillSeries
                End With
            End With
        Next currentArea
    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the result of F just E*10000? It doesn't matter too much, there's a few ways to solve.

1. Find your last row number (which you did as `lRow`)
2. Iterate `for i = 2 to lRow` which will loop from the top row with data to the last
3. Do something in here like `Range("F"&i) = Range("E"&i)*10000` assuming that is the relationship or `Range("F"&i) = Range("F"&i-1)+10000`
4. `next i`

it will just iterate cell by cell, make the calculation, and move on.

You may need to make it more robust if you have a script that hops around multiple sheets or workbooks so the range or cell or whatever references you use are correct.

Don't know how fast this would be vs the fill Series function but it doesn't look at face value like it would be too slow.

let me know how you get on!

Rob S

Comment: Ah, Yeah F is simply E*10000 but in my head that didn't come to my mind. Thanks for your help!